# Numpy Broadcast Function Across All Array Columns At Once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

To preface, looping across multidimensional arrays in Numpy using ndenumderate to perform operations is inefficient, particularly when the array is massive (on the order of millions of indices). With this in mind, I would like to apply a function across all columns (j) of an array's row (i) at once, which I believe is the same principle as broadcasting in Numpy.

Consider the following ndarray at row 0, which is of size `(2606, 8, 26)`. At each column j of this array, there are a total of 208 floating point integers across 8 separate arrays, which I'd like to flatten to one single array at column j. I've successfully executed this at a single index; the relevant code inside of a larger function to tackle this is as follows:

```
def lambdaloop():
    # There Are 1228 Rows In This Array
    for index in range(0,1228,1):
        # Series of Stored Arrays That Define A "Moving Window", Is Not Important To This Question
        segment = window[index, :]
        # "Moving Window" Partitions Values In A Separate ndarray 'stacked', Resultant Is Important To This Question
        inspect = stacked[segment[:,:,0], segment[:,:,1]]
        # Flattening The ndarray At Column 0. This Works Successfully, tolist() Could Also Be Used Here
        flat = inspect[0].flatten()
```

The result of `flat` is further below. I made a separate function with an embedded lambda function to pass to np.vectorize to broadcast this across all columns at once. I'm aware that np.vectorize is essentially a fancier looping mechanism, but other entries here indicate it can still be notably faster than moving across each column in a for loop. With additions, this is what I assembled:

```
def broadcast(piece):
    flatten = lambda piece: piece.flatten()
    return flatten
    
def lambdaloop():
    # There Are 1228 Rows In This Array
    for index in range(0,1228,1):
        # Series of Stored Arrays That Define A "Moving Window", Is Not Important To This Question
        segment = window[index, :]
        # "Moving Window" Partitions Values In A Separate ndarray 'stacked', Resultant Is Important To This Question
        inspect = stacked[segment[:,:,0], segment[:,:,1]]
        # Flattening The ndarray At Column 0. This Works Successfully, tolist() Could Also Be Used Here
        vfunc = np.vectorize(broadcast)
        vresult = vfunc(inspect)
```

Upon inspecting `vresult`, I find the following applied to every value in the ndarray: `<function broadcast.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fddc342ed40>`. How can I apply the broadcast function to return flatten arrays at each column j with a resultant shape (2606,208)?

For clarity, the result of `flat` (and what I expect for each array to look like across all columns) looks as follows:

```
[0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 1.46875   2.6875    0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        1.78125   2.21875
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        3.1640625 2.625     0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        1.78125   2.21875   0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        3.6640625
 1.09375   0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        1.        2.71875   0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        2.90625   2.15625   0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.
 1.1875    2.4375    0.        0.        0.       ]
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question; sorry. Side note, have you looked at `np.reshape`? It might be relevant/useful.

Comment: I have looked at reshape some, indeed! Basically I'd like to flatten each of these ndarrays across all columns at row 0 at once using this function, if possible. I'd expect that the result from this would be a 2-D array shaped 2606 by the number of values in each flattened array, so 208. Does that clarify this somewhat and would np.reshape execute the same task without the need for this function?

Comment: If `a` has shape `(2606, 8, 26)`,  then `b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1)` has shape `(2606, 208)`.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: Careful about `vectorize`.  It passes scalars to the function, not arrays or rows or columns.  While it does seem to scale better than a direct iteration, it is never "notably faster".

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that is exactly what I'm looking for and never considered until now. A follow-up question: could I reshape over multiple rows at once either in a function or via broadcasting in Numpy?